# Check if input is one single letter (Java)

Tags: java

In my program, I get a user input (String):

ex:

```
String input = in.nextline();
```

I want to check (with an if-function) if the user/string has the following:

- contains a letter (a-z / A-Z)
- only contains one letter (A is valid, AA/AB/LWA is invalid)

so what goes on x/x2?

```
if(input.equals(x) && input.equals(x2){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Do you really a `if(input.equals(x) && input.equals(x2){ ... } ` solution? Why? What have you tried?

Comment: im not an advanced java programmer. I just want two outputs. One if the sring does contain only one letter, and if it doest. I just dont know how to check if the input is a letter anmd only one letter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex for that:

```
String input = in.nextline():
if (input.matches("[A-Za-z]{1}")) {
    //valid input
}
else {
    //invalid input
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution that doesn't involve regular expressions (and, as such, can be easier understood) is simply:

- check that the length of the String is 1, using [`String.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--).
- check that the first character is between `'a'` and `'z'` or between `'A'` and `'Z'`, using [`String.charAt(index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) and doing integer comparison on the ASCII value of the characters. This can be also simplified by lowercasing the character and checking that it is between `'a'` and `'z'` only.

A sample code would be:

```
private static boolean isValid(String str) {
    if (str.length() != 1) return false;
    char c = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(0));
    return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';
}
```

And you would use it like

```
String input = in.nextline();
if (isValid(input)) {
    // do something wonderful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `regex` should do the work:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    if (input.matches("[A-z]")) {
        System.out.println("Valid input");
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }
```

Comment: `A-z`? Why are you assuming `a` is after `Z`?

Comment: '[A-z]' contains all capitals and small letters - once each

Comment: No it doesn't. There are a few more characters between `Z` and `a`. Google ascii.

Comment: You're right, I'll give you that... Thanks for the remark - but still it does the trick if you want to : "how to check if the input is a letter and only one letter"

Comment: If the input is `_`, your code will write `Valid input`. That doesn't do the trick imo.